# Match block of strings from a text file

Tags: python, loops, match, string-search

i read multiple discussions similar to my issue but i can't find a working solution!
I have a txt file make like that:

```
blah L1 blah 
**ON**
...(uninteresting)
...(uninteresting)

conf1
...(uninteresting)
...(uninteresting)

port1:   3 blah blah

port2:  8 blah blah

port3:   0 blah blah

port4:   0 blah blah

conf2
...(uninteresting)
...(uninteresting)

port1:   21 blah blah

port2:  18 blah blah

port3:   0 blah blah

port4:   1 blah blah


conf3
...(uninteresting)
...(uninteresting)

port1:   42 blah blah

port2:  38 blah blah

port3:   2 blah blah

port4:   5 blah blah

**ON_2K**
...(uninteresting)
...(uninteresting)

conf1
...(uninteresting)
...(uninteresting)

port1:   3 blah blah

port2:  8 blah blah

port3:   0 blah blah

port4:   0 blah blah

conf2
...(uninteresting)
...(uninteresting)

port1:   21 blah blah

port2:  18 blah blah

port3:   0 blah blah

port4:   1 blah blah


conf3
...(uninteresting)
...(uninteresting)

port1:   42 blah blah

port2:  38 blah blah

port3:   2 blah blah

port4:   5 blah blah

etc. etc.
```

What I would like to do is to fill some different pandas dataframes with the numbers written in those lines matching "port#:   42 blah blah" depending on different configurations.
So in total 2 different df like that:

`df_L1_ON = pd.DataFrame(index =['conf1', 'conf2','conf3'], columns =['PORT1', 'PORT2','PORT3', 'PORT4'])`

`df_L1_ON_2k = pd.DataFrame(index =['conf1', 'conf2','conf3'], columns =['PORT1', 'PORT2','PORT3', 'PORT4'])`

In general I used to find matches in files and get the part that I want like that:

```
with open("file") as g:
    for line in g:
        if " " in line: continue
        if " port1 " in line:
             vals = line.split()
             x.append(float(vals[2]))
```

but in this case I need a deeper parsing because I need to get a nested value, id est:

1. find "ON"
2. search in the subsequent lines "conf#"
3. search in subsequent lines "port#" & split line & append to the correct df index

and this has to be done for each conf, each port for both "ON" and "ON_2K".
I know it's a big challenge but I appreciate any suggestion. I spoke about python but (as the title suggest) if you have a more easy way in bash please still answer!
Thanks

Comment: So for  `port#: 42 blah blah` you want to put `42` in your dataframe?

Comment: And are there more numbers in "blah blah" part that you want to ignore?

Comment: That's right! I just want the 42 but i think this could be done with something like: vals = line.split() and x.append(float(vals[2])). And no, there are no other numbers!

Comment: sorry x.append(float(vals[1]))